# How can I untrack/ignore a folder in an old branch without commiting the new changes?

Tags: git, git-branch, gitignore

Basically I accidentally added the 'files' folder to my commits, so I have four old branches of development that have the 'files' folder listed, with all the files.
I don't want to make any other changes to these branches, I just want to remove the files folder, and leave everything else exactly as it is.
I tried Googling it with no luck?
I'm assuming I'm missing something easy, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you just want to remove it from the next commit, or remove it from the project history entirely?

`git rm BAD_DIRECTORY && git commit -a` will do the former. You should use this method if you've shared this repository publicly, as rewriting history will de-sync other's repos from yours.

To do the latter, use `git filter-branch`. It rewrites history by applying a sequence of filters (commands) to the project at each state (commit) in the history. For your use case, you can use something like:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch BAD_DIRECTORY"
```

By using `--index-filter`, you avoid having to do a checkout at each commit, saving some time. Check out the manual page for more information. Adding `--ignore-unmatch` to `git rm` keeps it from failing if BAD_DIRECTORY doesn't exist at a particular commit.

Comment: I believe removing it from the project history entirely is what I need.
My 'master' and 'update_05' branches do not have the BAD_DIRECTORY, because I removed it with<br />
`code`git rm -r --cached files/*`code`<br />
Yet with branches 'update_01' through 'update_04' it still exists.

Comment: After removing it from master, I would suggest rebasing update_05 on top of the new master. As long as update_05 doesn't modify the BAD_DIR, you shouldn't have to filter both branches.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. One final question about this if I can. after doing `code`git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch files/*"`code`, which looked like it worked, how do I safely push these to github so they remove the 'files' directory as well?

Comment: @JesseGangi you can `git push --force`: it will publish the new history you just created through your filter-branch.

Comment: It will also desync the repos of anyone who's pulled from your public repo, as I explained in my answer. Be sure this is acceptable to you.

Comment: I guess I'm in that lucky spot where no one has pulled from me yet. I'm still green with git. Thanks a bunch for the help!